# vbscript retain leading zeroes when converting txt to xlsx

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I'm trying to convert a text file (tab delimited) to `xlsx`. The below script does the conversion successfully but it removes the leading 0s, I tried formatting all cells to text beforehand using

```
objWorkSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
```

but it the result still has no leading zeroes even
though all cells are formatted to text. 
Is there anything i can add to the code to make it retain leading 0s? Thank you

```
 Function convert()
Const xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote = 1
Const xlInsertDeleteCells = 1
Const xlDelimited = 1

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Visible = False
objExcel.DisplayAlerts= False

strCSVfile = "C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\a.txt"
strXLSfile = "C:\Users\xxxx\Downloads\b.xlsx"

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add
Set objWorkSheet = objWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
objWorkSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
With objWorkSheet.QueryTables.Add("TEXT;" & strCSVfile, objWorkSheet.Range("$A$1"))
    .Name = "input"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 437
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "#"
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh False
End With

'Save Spreadsheet, 51 = Excel 2007-2010
objWorkSheet.SaveAs strXLSfile, 51

'Release Lock on Spreadsheet
objExcel.Quit()
Set ObjExcel = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Adding a single quote `'` before the values works, although it's not the cleanest solution.